# Gource on Windows

Tags: windows, video, gource

We're having problems on windows creating a video file from gource ([gource](http://code.google.com/p/gource/)). We can run gource and watch the video live but don't seem to be able to get any useful physical output.

Comment: Could you provide the full command line you are using to run gource? Also, what is the error message (symptoms)?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
gource -1024x768 --stop-position 1.0 --highlight-all-users --hide-filenames --seconds-per-day 5 --output-framerate 60 --output-ppm-stream output.ppm

ffmpeg -y -r 60 -f image2pipe -vcodec ppm -i output.ppm  -vcodec wmv1 -r 60 -qscale 0 out.wmv
```

The key was the image2pipe format which seems to extract all the frames from the ppm rather than treating it as an individual image.

Comment: ffmpeg doesnt seem to work for me untlil i giva him path: C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg -y -r 60 -f image2pipe -vcodec ppm -i  output.ppm -vcodec libvpx -fpre "C:\\ffmpeg\\presets\\libvpx-360p.ffpreset" gource.avi

Comment: Adding ffmpeg to my path variable then executing this in the folder where the output.ppm file was worked for me. ffmpeg -y -r 60 -f image2pipe -vcodec ppm -i output.ppm -vcodec libvpx -fpre "C:\\Program Files\\ffmpeg\\presets\\libvpx-1080p.ffpreset" gource.avi

Answer (score 1):

Presets are now deprecated.

Here's what I used.

```
gource -f -3840x2160 --camera-mode  track  --file-idle-time 150  --max-file-lag 4 --seconds-per-day 2 --highlight-all-users --output-framerate 30 --output-ppm-stream output.ppm

ffmpeg -i output.ppm -c:v libx264 -crf 24 -preset veryslow output.mp4
```

More info here:

https://superuser.com/questions/490683/cheat-sheets-and-presets-settings-that-actually-work-with-ffmpeg-1-0

> FFmpeg does not include text file based presets and profiles anymore
>   for libx264, i.e. what you've used with the -vpre option. These have
>   been depreciated and removed in favor of accessing the actual x264
>   presets, profiles (and tunes) with the -preset, -profile:v, and -tune
>   options. The old text files only emulated the official x264 presets
>   and profiles, and due to several limitations could not offer full
>   functionality that the new system provides. It is also much easier to
>   maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I made gource video on windows with this program [SmartPixel](http://www.smartpixel.com/).
Just make gource go fullscreen like that:

gource --fullscreen

In setting you just need to turn off watermark.
Any game/video capturing software serves same purpose.

Usefull options:

gource --fullscreen --save-config config.txt

Saves current options in text file and you can see what its look like
egzample file content from above:
[display]
fullscreen=true

gource --load-config config.txt

Loads from config